# Python with DataFrame merge of aggregations ...error: '' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, aggregate

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
{'File': '7396ee8aea09.json', 'Last': '2019-04-25 20:24:28+00:00', 'Size': 78796, 'COLA': 'STANDARD'}, 
{'File': '7777682e4/ip/done', 'Last': '2019-04-24 21:45:01+00:00', 'Size': 4, 'COLA': 'CUSTOM'}, 
{'File': 'erparameters.json', 'Last': '2019-04-24 21:45:01+00:00', 'Size': 351, 'COLA': 'STANDARD'}
]
data2 = [
{'File': '3343e4/ip/ip.json', 'Last': '2019-04-24 21:45:01+00:00', 'Size': 20, 'COLA': 'STANDARD'}, 
{'File': 'ta-00000-of-00001', 'Last': '2019-04-24 22:43:17+00:00', 'Size': 140216236, 'COLA': 'STANDARD'}, 
{'File': '-20514.ckpt.index', 'Last': '2019-04-24 22:43:17+00:00', 'Size': 3168, 'COLA': 'STANDARD'}, 
]
# right now 2 for the prova but could be much more..
datas = [data1, data2]
results = None 
for data in datas:
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['COLA','Size','Last'])\
              .groupby(['COLA'])\
              .agg({
                  'COLA': [('COLA', 'max'), ('Count', 'count')],
                  'Size': [('Size', 'sum')],
                  'Last': [('Last', 'max')]
                  })
  df.columns = ['COLA', 'Count', 'Size', 'Last']

  if results is None:
    results = df
  else:
    results = results.merge(df,
                   on=['COLA', 'Count', 'Size', 'Last'],
                   how='outer',
                   )\
             .groupby(['COLA'], as_index=False)\
             .agg({
                   'COLA': [('COLA', 'max'), ('Count', 'sum')],
                   'Size': [('Size', 'sum')],
                   'Last': [('Last', 'max')]
                 })

print (results)
```

expected results is in that format:

- COLA have all unique COLA labels
- Size is the sum of all 'Size' for that COLA label group across all
  sets.
- Count is the total count of that COLA label group across all sets.
- Last has the greatest date of that COLA label group across all sets.

Example:

```
results = [
     {'COLA': 'STANDARD', 'Size': 140298571, 'Count': 5, 'Last': '2019-04-25 20:24:28+00:00'}, 
     {'COLA': 'CUSTOM',   'Size': 4,         'Count': 1, 'Last': '2019-04-24 21:45:01+00:00'}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate all the data and do groupby:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(d) for d in datas)

(df.groupby('COLA').agg({'COLA':'count',
                        'Size':'max',
                        'Last':'max'})
  .rename(columns={'COLA':'Count'})
  .reset_index()
  .to_dict('rows')
)
```

Output:

```
[{'COLA': 'CUSTOM',
  'Count': 1,
  'Size': 4,
  'Last': '2019-04-24 21:45:01+00:00'},
 {'COLA': 'STANDARD',
  'Count': 5,
  'Size': 140216236,
  'Last': '2019-04-25 20:24:28+00:00'}]
```

---

**Update**: I haven't tried this, but this should work and require less memory:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(d)
                 .groupby('COLA')
                 .agg({'COLA':'count',
                       'Size':'max',
                       'Last':'max'})
                 .rename(columns={'COLA':'Count'})
               for data in datas
               )

df.groupby('COLA').agg({'Count':'sum', 'Size':'max', 'last':'max'})
```

Comment: Would that cause a memory issue if I have millions of rows in each data set?

Comment: As long as you loaded all the datasets in to `datas`, I think you would be fine. If not, you can `groupby` each dataset in your for loop with the same command, concatenate the results and `groupby` again, this time aggregate with `'Count':'sum'` and without `rename`.

Comment: Thanks! That really simplify my code and reduce many loops.. One more issue is when the .to_dict('rows') ... it give me the lables as ('COLA',''):   and ('Count','Count'): ...

Comment: That I'm not sure, the code works for the sample data. Maybe your data is a bit different.

Comment: The issue was in the way I was doing the agg...  I did not noticed the change you did..  All good now!! Many thanks!!

Comment: can you give me the sample code for the first comment about the loop? I'm not sure I get the "loop with the same command" and the change to 'Count':'sum'..

Comment: getting:  pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported,  I f I remove the rename I loose my entry for 'COLA': 'CUSTOM' or 'COLA':'STANDARD' as part of the results

Comment: Got it! I had to add "as_index=False" in the groupby's